# Erro mesmo tendo o método de click

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar com um erro chato com ASP.NET? 
Seguinte... Tenho um botão:

```
<asp:Button ID="cadastra" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Cadastrar Cliente" onclick="cadastra_Click1" />
```

E tenho o método `cadastra_Click1`

```
protected void cadastra_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write("<script>alert('clockado');</script>");
}
```

Quando tento rodar o código o compilador me traz o seguinte erro:

> CS1061: 'ASP.cadcliente_aspx' não contém uma definição para 'cadastra_Click1' e nenhum método de extensão 'cadastra_Click1' aceita que um primeiro argumento de tipo 'ASP.cadcliente_aspx' seja encontrado (você não está usando uma diretriz ou referência de assembly?)

Não sei mais o que fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente apagar o botão e criar novamente com o projeto parado.
Se você adicionar um botão com o projeto rodando as vezes ele não adiciona no `designer.cs`, e outra, certifique que não renomeou a pagina copiou e colou e renomeou ou algo do tipo pois o código pode estar apontado para um fonte antigo sem o método.

No topo do `aspx` tem um trecho que informa onde está o `codebehind`
 `CodeBehind="SuaPagina.aspx.cs"` o método deve estar nesse arquivo

Comment: Deu certo, porém o erro continuou e achei onde era, era numa classe que tinha referência com o evento do click. Valeu a ajuda! @adrianolsk